# PHP And Node.JS - Crypto PBKDF2

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I am trying to get Node.JS Crypto PBKDF2 to match same value from PHP Crypto PBKDF2. For some reason, it is not the same.

In JavaScript

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.pbkdf2('secret', 'salt', 100000, 20, 'sha512', (err, key) => {

  console.log(key.toString()); 
});
```

Output: `7E������]�9��J]�i`

In PHP

```
$password = "secret";
$iterations = 100000;
$salt = "salt";

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);
echo $hash;
```

Output: `3745e482c6e0ade35da1`

Why JS output is not matching PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option **raw_output** of the [hash_pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) method in PHP and compare their base64

**In PHP**

```
<?php
$password = "secret";
$iterations = 100000;
$salt = "salt";

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20, true);
echo base64_encode($hash);
?>
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/6GIcf)

**In NodeJS**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.pbkdf2('secret', 'salt', 100000, 20, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
console.log(new Buffer(key).toString('base64'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seem to work! Is it possible to do something with password_hash() in JavaScript?

Comment: You are welcome. What do you want to do with password_hash() ?

Comment: When a hash are generated via password_hash() then in JS should be verifying a Password Against A Hash that were created in PHP.

Comment: You have to use a javascript implementation of the PHP Password Library but it's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

PHP string is in hexadecimal format. Node.JS string isn't.

**UPDATE :** `key.toString('hex')` in JS solve the problem.

**Source :** https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback

Comment: I have tried converting to HEX and also base64, still not matching.

Comment: I add some code from documentation which must solve your problem.

Comment: That seem to work but on JS it showing more length hash than PHP. On PHP `3745e482c6e0ade35da1` but on JS: `3745e482c6e0ade35da10139e797157f4a5da669`

Comment: Changing to 20 to 10 length on JS fixed it.. odd?

Comment: Strange bug, because PHP key has the good length. Perhaps something is a little buggy in *node.js* api.

Comment: Shameful, but not buggy. "'hex' - Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters." --[source](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encoding). So, OP said he wants a 20 *byte* key, `buf.toString('hex')` returns a string with two characters per byte, which means 40 character string.  PHP implementation just assumes you mean 20 *character* key. I'm not sure which is the dumber behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! :)